# On change in cell blink font one time in red and blue on negative and positive value base on next cell like Stock Market

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

If D2:D14 are in Minus then C2:C14 will be in red font blink on change C2:C14 one time only
If D2:D14 are in plus then C2:C14 will be in Blue font blink on change C2:C14 one time only

Like Stock Market Blink on plus and minus Click for Test File [Test File for Blink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KWVs-9I387zvOPTG5jxmtTpfOYrnchYhA5sFeCjuims/edit?usp=sharing)

Some thing like this https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/168502/blinking-cells-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onEdit simple trigger to do that. Whenever any value is updated in the sheet, this function will automatically be triggered. It will check if the edited value is in the range D2:D14, and if yes, it would blink the corresponding value in the C column to blue or red.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = e.range;

  // Check if the edited cell is in the range D2:D14
  if (editedRange.getColumn() == 4 && editedRange.getRow() >= 2 && editedRange.getRow() <= 14) {
    // Cell to be blinked
    var cellToBeBlinked = sheet.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), editedRange.getColumn() - 1, 1, 1);
    var editedVal = parseFloat(e.value.replace('%', ''));

    // Blink to blue or red based on whether the change is +ve and -ve
    if (editedVal > 0) {
      cellToBeBlinked = cellToBeBlinked.setFontColor("blue");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      cellToBeBlinked.setFontColor("black");
    }
    else if (editedVal < 0) {
      cellToBeBlinked = cellToBeBlinked.setFontColor("red");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      cellToBeBlinked.setFontColor("black");
    }
  }
}
```

This really works but I would recommend you to try it out and check the performance once if you are expecting a very large dataset in future.

Comment: is it Blink one times or keep red or blue? my mean on change only and one time and rest black

Comment: Oh yes, I had missed the blink earlier. Updated the answer now to include that. It would blink to blue/red and then again change the color to black.